# How to show/hide web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, jquery, hide

On a SharePoint page, I have two web parts: One web part displays root Documents folder and another web part on the side is just a text that provides some tips to users. But when a user clicks on any sub-folder in the Documents web part the tips web part should hide. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can hide the tip web part based on clicking on subfolders since

1. You cannot ensure the contents to stay the same.
2. The page gets refreshed every time you click on a subfolder.

However, you can hide a web part with a onclick method with JavaScript. It adds a button to the page and hide the web part when you click the button.

Please see the references below:

[Hide SharePoint web part using javascript onclick method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226720/hide-sharepoint-web-part-using-javascript-onclick-method)

[hide/show webpart data on buttonclick using jquery.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c437ecc4-c757-483f-8175-f92860d184be/hideshow-webpart-data-on-buttonclick-using-jquery?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: Thank you Chelsea. I hope someone either confirms this or suggests a solution(or at least hint)